# Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js" - React Native + How to Solve?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobile-development, react-navigation-stack, stack-navigator

undefined Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/native` from `App.js`: @react-navigation/native could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

```
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:307:41 in showCompileError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:228:26 in client.on$argument_1
- node_modules\eventemitter3\index.js:181:39 in emit
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\WebSocketHMRClient.js:80:20 in _ws.onmessage
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\WebSocket\WebSocket.js:232:27 in _eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
> Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js"
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/native" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
```

[image]

Please Help Me.
Email ID: roy.sounak01@gmail.com

Comment: Followed all the steps given in this getting started guide? 
 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Comment: if you are already running the app and at the same time installed the dependencies, then you have to relaunch it.

Answer (score 30):

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

if using expo:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Also run:

```
npm install react-navigation
```

Comment: Why do we need all these dependencies?

Comment: Also restart the server after running these commands ;)

Answer (score 14):

This error occurs because you haven't installed react-navigation.

Run:

```
npm install react-navigation
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 7):

the best solution is to delete your node_modules and package-lock.json and try npm install, it worked for me

Comment: This seems straight forward but it works

Answer (score 2):

well i have solved this by reinstalling / updating these packages.

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

do the trick for

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

But performing the following did succeed:

Delete

> node_modules & package-lock.json Delete app from phone

```
run npm start -- --reset-cache
run app
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line to your **metro.config.js**

```
sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you have to restart your app, do npm run... to start a new server if you are using expo.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to stale cache. To fix this,
Run:
npm start -c //This is if you're using expo

if you're not using expo,
Run:
npx react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck on same issue for a whole day at last deleting packagelock.json and node module folder with using

try resetting the cache

after that npm start

and at last run: npx react-native run-android

and now all the files will be rebuild and your navigation container should be working

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when I was looking for a solution as I had a similar problem. You can use `yarn` commands in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) instead of `npm`.

If it persits, change

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

to:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from './node_modules/@react-navigation/native;
```

I had made that changes before using the `yarn` commands

While running the build, use:

```
npx react-native start
```