# React native: "Failed building JavaScript bundle. Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js""

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I am using react-native and I am trying to add navigation to my project. When I add this line of code:

`import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";`, I get this error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/stack" from "App.js"
```

I tried all the solutions suggested in this **stackoverflow** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975287/unable-to-resolve-react-navigation-native-from-app-js-react-native-how) but, none worked for me! I reinstalled everything using these commands more than once.

I am using expo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use stackNavigator, you should install dependencies separately.

After install @react-navigation/native, install @react-navigation/stack:

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

[Tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) says that:

> To use this navigator, ensure that you have @react-navigation/native and its dependencies (follow this guide), then install @react-navigation/stack:
>
> npm install @react-navigation/stack

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while using expo.

My solution was just to start expo with the flag to clear the Metro bundler cache

```
expo start -c
```